# How do I use an int and printf

Tags: java

I need to use the following in my program and not sure how to get it to work.

> Ask the user to enter their name(String variable) and age (int
>   variable).

Also I need to display their name, age and a welcome message using a printf statement.

This is what I have so far.  Can anyone help me?  Please

```
package myfirstprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyFirstProgram {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String name;
       int age; 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Please Type Your Name then press the Enter key.");
        System.out.printf("Please Type Your Age then press the Enter Key.");
        name = sc.next();
        age = sc.next();
        System.out.printf("Hello. My name is " + name + ", I am pleased to meet you.");
        System.out.printf("Your Age is " + age);
        System.out.printf("Hello and Welcome, " + name);
    }

}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Well for one thing, `Scanner.next()` returns a string. It should be `age = sc.nextInt();`.

Comment: Have you read a tutorial on this first? You should and when asking a question, you should try to use it as the tutorial shows you, something you're not doing. You're using it as if it's nothing but a println call.

Comment: Speak of the devil! Why, here's the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) right here!

Comment: Otherwise this question reads as, "please do my homework for me" or "please re-write a tutorial for me". Not good.

Comment: change age = sc.nextInt() instead of age = sc.next().because age is int type.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even try to compile your code to see what errors are in it?
Are you using a GUI program (like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), et al.) to compile your code? Or `javac` on the [command-line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)? Either way your code compiles with the error:

```
javac myfirstprogram/MyFirstProgram.java
myfirstprogram/MyFirstProgram.java:17: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
        age = sc.next();
                     ^
1 error
```

This is saying that, as shmosel and others rightly pointed out in the comments, `Scanner.next()` returns a string, which is fine when you are getting the user's `name` input that is of type `String`, but this won't work for `age` input as you have defined `age` as an `int`.
So to "get it to work" you need to do as the compiler instructs which is to change the line 17 to:
`age = sc.nextInt();`
Then your program should "work" as you expect.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    int age;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Please enter your name");
    name = sc.next();
    System.out.printf("Please enter your age");
    age = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Hello " + name + "\nYour age is: " + age);
    sc.close();
}
```

The reason this code works is because, like others have said, the age variable is an integer, not a String (what sc.next() returns). Also, it is much easier to separate both questions because that way the program will easily distinguish what is being inputted as the age and the name.

If you want it to be a bit more fail proof, you can throw an exception that will check to see that the user did not input a String as an integer.

A good place to see how libraries work in Java is both Stackoverflow and the Java API website (depending on your version of Java there are different sites)

[Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 7
API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html)

[Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 8
API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html)

If you need help with anything else in Java and the above is complicated, try these websites:

[Tutorials Point - Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)

Best of luck!